# knockout foreach add row number to grid

Tags: arrays, knockout-3.0

I have this grid that fills an array within an array.
It creates according to one array and then fills that column with another array.

[image: Like]

```
 <div id="formula" data-bind="with:currentFormula">
        <!-- ko foreach:$parent.tones-->
        <div class="col-sm-2" data-bind="foreach:$parents[1].levels">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail img-responsive" data-bind="click: $root.hasCurrent() ? $root.currentFormula().setEnding.bind($index(),$parentContext.$index())  : $root.currentFormula().setStarting.bind($index(),$parentContext.$index())">
                <img data-bind="attr:{ src: '/Content/images/colors/' +  $index() +  $parentContext.$index() + '.png' }" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko-->
    </div>
```

What I need to do is create a new column before col 1 and add the $index() + 1, or row number would work to that column.

I've looked all over and have not found anything that works.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your rows are being created based on `currentFormula.tones` within `<!-- ko foreach:$parent.tones-->` and columns based on `tones.levels`. So you should create a `div` that binds its text to `$index() + 1` only if the first `level` (column). To do this, you will need to move your loop for creating columns up above the `div` that will represent the column.

Something like this:

```
<div id="formula" data-bind="with: currentFormula">
    <!-- ko foreach:$parent.tones-->
        <!-- ko foreach:$parents[1].levels -->
            <!-- If this is the first level/column, then create a new column to show rownum  -->
            <div class="col-sm-2" data-bind="if: $index() == 0, text: 'Row ' + $parent.$index() + 1"></div>
            <!-- Normal column creation -->
            <div class="col-sm-2" >
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail img-responsive" data-bind="click: $root.hasCurrent() ? $root.currentFormula().setEnding.bind($index(), $parentContext.$index()) : $root.currentFormula().setStarting.bind($index(), $parentContext.$index())">
                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: '/Content/images/colors/' + $index() + $parentContext.$index() + '.png' }" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko-->
    <!-- /ko-->
</div>
```